# MySql Select query (limited selected on JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a 2 tables:  `tbl_customers`, and `tbl_customers_notes`

I'm displaying all my customers in table rows (as one does), and I want to add a column that is for displaying the last known `datetime` record in the related `tbl_customers_notes` table.

Obviously this is a one-to-many relationship where the matching recID is going to be `customerid`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `customername` FROM `tbl_customers` ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
?>  
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $customername;?></td>
      <td><?php echo 'note datetime'; ?></td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
```

If I do a JOIN with the notes table I get duplicates. Can I limit the `tbl_customers_notes` to just select the last known record for that customerid?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select c.customerid, c.customername, max(cn.note_date)
from tbl_customers c
left join tbl_customers_notes cn on c.customerid = cn.customerid
group by  c.customerid, c.customername
```

The reason for grouping by both customerid and customername is that in case same customername could have different customerids.  Outer join is to include customers that have no notes.

Comment: I agree with the multiple grouping, but I believe this would return multiple rows for some customers, with the date for all of them set to the most recent date.  Adding a `DISTINCT` might clear that up, though.

Comment: If database allows differenct customers have same name, then frontend app should not treat it as duplicated names, it can't use Distinct. If customername is defined as unique, then only group by customername would be enough.

Comment: That wasn't my point.  If there are multiple notes about a customer, you would end up with data that has a customerid, their customername, and the most recent date of their notes multiple times.  The `DISTINCT` will, ultimately, return only one row per customerid.

Comment: Because it's using group by customerid and customername from tbl_customer, and select only these two fields and max of note_date, nothing else from note table, this would guaranty return only one row per customerid. No need to use Distinct.

Comment: Ah, you're right, nevermind.  I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `customername`, max_datetime FROM `tbl_customers` c left join 
    (select max(datetime) max_datetime, customerid 
    from tbl_customers_notes cn group by customerid) cn on 
 on c.id=cn.customerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `HAVING` is in order.

```
SELECT c.customername, n.note_date
FROM tbl_customers c
         INNER JOIN tbl_customers_notes n ON c.customerid = n.customerid
GROUP BY c.customername
HAVING n.note_date = MAX(n.note_date)
```